# connecting postgres with sqlalchemy to a discord bot

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have tried to run a discord bot, but I'm stucked to run in a database, and I don't can solve this

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from inhouse_bot.database_orm import bot_declarative_base 
import sqlalchemy


def migrate():
    # TODO This should be removed in favor of a true database migration tool like Alembic

    # We create the engine to connect to the database
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(os.environ["postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/yohouse-yodismo"])
```

and when I run the bot this appears:

```
"KeyError: 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/yohouse-yodismo' "
```

Comment: I would think the error is down to this:`os.environ["postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/yohouse-yodismo"]`. Have no idea why you are looking up the connection string as an environment variable. Lose the `os.environ[]`.

Comment: ok, now appears `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'` you know how resolve this?

Comment: Without seeing the code as modified this is unanswerable. You can't make changes, not show what those changes are and then expect people to magically come up a solution. Add the modified code and complete traceback to your question.